Why is my CursorTool not working?
Now I want to draw lines, and I tried the advice from @ianturton, but the extension of CursorTool doesn't work for me. The onMouseClicked method does nothing when the mouse is pressed, I check this by displaying the number with the system.out.println() method, as an indicator of whether it has been started. Example from @ianturton
    package priprema;

import org.geotools.api.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
import org.geotools.api.style.Style;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureBuilder;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder;
import org.geotools.map.Layer;
import org.geotools.map.MapContent;
import org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS;
import org.geotools.styling.SLD;
import org.geotools.swing.JMapFrame;
import org.geotools.swing.MapPane;
import org.geotools.swing.action.MapAction;
import org.geotools.swing.event.MapMouseEvent;
import org.geotools.swing.tool.CursorTool;
import org.geotools.swing.tool.ZoomInTool;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;

import javax.sound.sampled.Line;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Map{
  private String id;
  private final MapContent map;
  private final JMapFrame mapFrame;
  private final JButton btn;
  private Map.DigitilizeMap digitizer;// poslje popravke
  

  public Map() {

    this.map = new MapContent();
    this.mapFrame = new JMapFrame();
    this.btn = new JButton("draw");
    
    mapFrame.enableToolBar(true);
    mapFrame.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 1080); 
    JToolBar toolBar = mapFrame.getToolBar();



    
    this.digitizer = this.new DigitilizeMap();
    btn.addActionListener(this.new DigitizerAction(this.mapFrame.getMapPane(), digitizer));
    toolBar.add(btn);

    mapFrame.add(toolBar);
    mapFrame.setMapContent(map);

    mapFrame.show(true);
  }

  public class DigitilizeMap extends CursorTool {
    private static final SimpleFeatureType type;
    private static final SimpleFeatureBuilder builder;
    private static final Style style;

    static {
      var b = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
      b.setName("LayerLine");
      b.crs(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
      b.add("line", Line.class);
      type = b.buildFeatureType(); 
      builder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(type);
      style = SLD.createLineStyle(Color.black, 10);
      System.out.println("Postavio sam svojstva za crtanje.");
    }
    
    private final ArrayList<SimpleFeatureType> lastKnownFeatures = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Coordinate> tempCoord;
    private Layer tempLayer;
    private double lastX, lastY;
    private boolean frst;
    

    @Override
    public void onMouseClicked(MapMouseEvent e) {// problem 1. sto mora non stat, aaaaamovic
      System.out.println("cuem");

        if (e.getClickCount() > 1) {
          this.drawLine(tempCoord);
          this.frst = true;
        } else {
          var pos = e.getWorldPos();
          this.tempCoord.add(new Coordinate(pos.getX(), pos.getY()));
          // ovo je bilo glavno
          if (!this.frst) {
            Graphics graphics = ((JComponent) getMapPane()).getGraphics().create();
            graphics.drawLine((int) this.lastX, (int) this.lastY, e.getX(), e.getY());
            this.lastX = e.getX();
            this.lastY = e.getY();


          } else {
            this.frst = false;
            this.lastX = e.getX();
            this.lastY = e.getY();

          }


        }

        }

    @Override
    public void onMouseExited(MapMouseEvent e) {

    }

    private void drawLine(ArrayList<Coordinate> tempCoord) {


    }

  }
  class DigitizerAction extends MapAction {
    private Map.DigitilizeMap dm;
    public DigitizerAction(MapPane mapPane, Map.DigitilizeMap d) {
      this(mapPane, false);
      this.dm = d;
      System.out.println("1");
    }

    public DigitizerAction(MapPane mapPane, boolean showName) {
      String toolName = "Draw";
      super.init(mapPane, toolName, ZoomInTool.TOOL_TIP, ZoomInTool.ICON_IMAGE);
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
      this.getMapPane().setCursorTool(this.dm);
      System.out.println("2");
      
    }


  }

}



I just identified that the problem occurred when enabling the ToolBar display. After it was added to the broder from JMapFrame, the MapContent display is lost, that is, I cannot click on the MapViewport area so that the MapPane forwards that event to CursorTool or MouseAdapter. I tried to change the size with setDisplayArea for MapContent, but I can't change the size, as if the MapFrame has a LayoutManager that adjusts itself. How to return the display of MapContent after turning on the ToolBar, that will be my solution.
So the problem is that the MapContent that the cursor follows is hidden behind the toolbar.But I haven't found a solution for this
The image below shows the frame, after I set setLayout(FlowLayout), it is the best case. With the default layoutManager, I don't even have this little white square that should be the map (left)
I'm a student and I need to do the task of drawing lines, polygons.

None of your buttons/tools are working - possibly because you have no layers in the map, try making the existing tools work then see if your draw tool is called

I just identified that the problem occurred when enabling the ToolBar display. After it was added to the broder from JMapFrame, the MapContent display is lost, that is, I cannot click on the MapViewport area so that the MapPane forwards that event to CursorTool or MouseAdapter. I tried to change the size with setDisplayArea for MapContent, but I can't change the size, as if the MapFrame has a LayoutManager that adjusts itself. How to return the display of MapContent after turning on the ToolBar, that will be my solution.

@Ian Turton So the problem is that the MapContent that the cursor follows is hidden behind the toolbar.But I haven't found a solution for this.

The main problem is that you add the toolbar to the MapFrame twice, since you get it from the MapFrame you can just add to it and don't need to add it back.
A second problem is that you haven't initialised the Coordinate array tempCoord and the boolean first (it defaults to false). I also added a working method to build the line layer:
    private ArrayList<Coordinate> tempCoord = new ArrayList<>();
    private Layer tempLayer;
    private double lastX, lastY;
    private boolean frst = true;

    public Layer getLayerLineByCoord(Coordinate[] coords) throws SchemaException {
        GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
        LineString line = geometryFactory.createLineString(coords);
        SimpleFeatureType TYPE = DataUtilities.createType("test", "line", "the_geom:LineString");
        SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder((SimpleFeatureType) TYPE);
        featureBuilder.add(line);
        SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature("LineString_Sample");

        DefaultFeatureCollection lineCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection();
        lineCollection.add(feature);

        Style style = SLD.createLineStyle(Color.BLUE, 1);
        return new FeatureLayer(lineCollection, style);
    }


Yes, that's a problem, but it doesn't apply to this part that I got to. I usually don't write the whole code, but the part where I stop to test if it works. The problem is that I don't know how to define the layout of the components in the frame, because the folder is so small and somewhere on the right, and I can't even when I set to setLayout(null) to make the frame have a different layout. So everything would be solved if I somehow managed to discover the hidden contents of the map

I added a picture to the question, so we understand

I am grateful to you
I just went to solve the first problem, which didn't seem like a problem to me, but it was the main thing. Can you explain to me what happened? I understood that I acquired an already existing (for customization) ToolBar from JMapFrame, then modified it (added a tool/button), and then naively added it again, resulting in it appearing in the display field (price) as a component, and that bothers the scheduler. However, such an opinion is strange to me, because if ToolBars were added in Java to allow components to be hung on the Border, why was this ToolBar added to centr

So I solved everything, I just don't understand why it caused the problem. Where should I read it?

JMapFrame is self contained, if you want to control the layout etc then you should control everything yourself
